# Can I populate an html form select box with data from an google spreadsheet?

Tags: html, forms, google-sheets, populate

I have a simple html form with a single select box.  currently it is populated with 2 hardcoded 'select' options.

```
<html>
<form id="form1" name="form1">
  <select name="select" id="select">
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
    </select>
</form>    
</html>
```

Is it possible to populate the options with a list from a published google spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O3hRZ_Fv9ldbJ8PJDicDHMp-EDIj_azhx9S4NHSUVyc/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

I can access the actual spreadsheet. And the list will contain a variable number of projects up to about 350.

I know a bit of javascript so ideally in that language would be best but if a different one is required I can research that.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Google's Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/index) would be a good place to start.

But in order to populate an HTML page with the content of a spreadsheet you first need to retrieve the content by either using an AJAX request to the correct API endpoint or by using a PHP Library (check [this](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client) out for example).
As for further help, you'd have to describe your setup a little bit more and maybe show some of your PHP/JS code...

Comment: thanks for that.  I'm just planning the project at the minute and working through what functionality I may need so there is no code at the minute.  I did wonder though whether it could be done via Google Apps Script entirely rather than a separate html page linking to the spreadsheet.  I'll have a mess about with the spreadsheet API and HTML service there to see how i get on and come back if I'm stuck! - likely